# About Eclipse Java Login Processing Function

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I want to implement the login process, but I don't know why I can't get the login account from mysql.

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import model.LoginLogic;
import model.User;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //リクエストパラメータを取得
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String mail = request.getParameter("mail");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");

        User user = new User(mail, pass);

        //login process
        LoginLogic loginLogic = new LoginLogic();
        boolean isLogin = loginLogic.execute(user);

        if (isLogin) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("mail", user);

            //Forward to employee management system screen
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/employee_list.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        } else {
            //Forward to the login screen
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

```
package model;

import dao.LoginDAO;

public class LoginLogic {

    public boolean execute(User user) {
        LoginDAO loginDao = new LoginDAO();
        EmployeeBean employee = loginDao.selectAll(user);
        return employee != null;
    }
}
```

Declare that you want to login with mail and password

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 *
 *
 */

public class User implements Serializable {

    private String mail;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String mail, String password) {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public String getPassWord() {
        return password;
    }

}
```

The JavaBeans will look like the following.

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * Employee List
 *
 */

public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String userName;
    private String name;
    private String callname;
    private String birth;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    private int postal;
    private String country;
    private String address;
    private String entry;
    private String retirement;
    private String reason;
    private String phone;
    private String mail;
    private int mynumber;
    private String password;
    private String text;

    /**
     *  EmployeeBean　Construction
     */
    public EmployeeBean() {

    }

    public EmployeeBean(String id, String userName, String name, String callname, String birth, int age, String gender,
            String country, int postal, String address, String entry, String retirement,
            String reason, String phone, String mail, int mynumber, String password, String text) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setUserName(userName);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setCallname(callname);
        this.setBirth(birth);
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setGender(gender);
        this.setCountry(country);
        this.setPostal(postal);
        this.setAddress(address);
        this.setEntry(entry);
        this.setRetirement(retirement);
        this.setReason(reason);
        this.setPhone(phone);
        this.setMail(mail);
        this.setMynumber(mynumber);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.setText(text);

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBirth() {
        return birth;
    }

    public void setBirth(String birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getPostal() {
        return postal;
    }

    public void setPostal(int postal) {
        this.postal = postal;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(String entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public int getMynumber() {
        return mynumber;
    }

    public void setMynumber(int mynumber) {
        this.mynumber = mynumber;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getRetirement() {
        return retirement;
    }

    public void setRetirement(String retirement) {
        this.retirement = retirement;
    }

    public String getCallname() {
        return callname;
    }

    public void setCallname(String callname) {
        this.callname = callname;
    }
}
```

The JSP will look like the following.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ログイン</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Employee Management System</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="login">LOGIN</div>

    <form action="ManagementSystem/LoginServlet" method="post">
        <div class="border">
            <div class="idPass">
                Email <input type="text" name="mail"><br> 
                Password <input
                    type="password" name="password"><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form action="ManagementSystem/EmployeeAddSevlert" method="post">
        <div class="border">
            <div class="Registration">
                <button type="submit">SIGNUP</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The sql will look like the following.

```
+------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------+
| id   | username | name            | callname           | birth    | age  | gender | country | postal  | address   | entry    | retirement | reason | phone       | mail                    | mynumber  | password | text |
+------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------+
|    1 | Test     | テスト太郎      | てすとたろう       | 20101010 |   15 | 男     | 日本    | 1234567 | 埼玉県    | 20151212 | NULL       | NULL   | 08012345678 | testtest@gmail.com |      NULL | NULL     | NULL |
| NULL | NULL     | NULL            | NULL               | NULL     | NULL | NULL   | NULL    |    NULL | NULL      | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   | 08012341234 | test@gmail.com     | 123456789 | test     | NULL |
+------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+------+
```

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import model.EmployeeBean;
import model.User;

/**
 *
 * 
 *
 */

public class LoginDAO {

    final String jdbcId = "test";
    final String jdbcPass = "test";
    final String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emplyoee_db=false";

    public EmployeeBean selectAll(User user) {
        EmployeeBean employee = new EmployeeBean();

        //DB Connection
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcId, jdbcPass)) {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_table WHERE mail = ? AND password = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, user.getMail());
            pstmt.setString(2, user.getPassWord());

            ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery();

            if (res.next()) {
                employee.setId(res.getString("id"));
                employee.setUserName(res.getString("username"));
                employee.setName(res.getString("name"));
                employee.setCallname(res.getString("callname"));
                employee.setBirth(res.getString("birth"));
                employee.setAge(res.getInt("age"));
                employee.setGender(res.getString("gender"));
                employee.setCountry(res.getString("country"));
                employee.setPostal(res.getInt("postal"));
                employee.setAddress(res.getString("address"));
                employee.setEntry(res.getString("entry"));
                employee.setRetirement(res.getString("retirement"));
                employee.setReason(res.getString("reason"));
                employee.setPhone(res.getString("phone"));
                employee.setMail(res.getString("mail"));
                employee.setMynumber(res.getInt("mynumber"));
                employee.setPassword(res.getString("password"));
                employee.setText(res.getString("text"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return employee;
    }
}
```

There are no error messages.
I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Hi ,show `selectAll` method code as well.

Comment: Hello!
I have also displayed the code for selectAll.

Comment: Currently your code doesn't login ? Did you tried debugging ? Check if the values are set in bean or not then what exactly `isLogin` has ? is your query returns something ?

Comment: My apologies.
The reason was that I had specified <form action=""> as LoginServlet for Login.